# Xcode - Accessing object tags without a case statment

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4, tags, storyboard

I'm writing a mixer app that has multiple slider objects all with individual tags (from 0 - 5) . Is there a way to change their properties without using a switch statement. For example my code currently has to repeat itself in a load of case statements :

```
-(void)sliderupdate:(int)currentfader{
switch (currentfader) {
    case 0:
        channel0 = round(fader0.value*100);
        value0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",channel0];
        knob0.center = CGPointMake(...;
        mute0.backgroundColor = ...;
        break;
    case 1:
        channel1 = round(fader1.value*100);
        value1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",channel1];
        knob1.center = CGPointMake(...;
        mute1.backgroundColor = ...;
        break;
```

Can I simply write one expression like:

```
channel(x) = ....
value(x) = ....
knob(x) = ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can add those Channel objects in an NSMutableArray and access them by index. a different array for the values and a different one for knob. like:

```
[channelArray objectAtIndex:x];
[valueArray objectAtIndex:x];
[knob objectAtIndex:x];
```

just make sure you add them in the correct oder to their arrays.

Comment: Ok so how would you then adjust a particular parameter such as the knob1.center = ... in the array format? [knob ojectAtIndex:x].center presumably wouldn't be the way?

Comment: it is actually :)
[knobsArray objectAtIdex:x] is exactly the same as knob1 or knob2
autocomplete might not give u all the methods, if u NEED auto complete  cast the object returned from the array to the object type u want, say knob is a UIImageView then:
((UIImageView *)[knobsArray objectAtIdex:x]).center = ......

Comment: That's easier than I thought it would be. I think I've made a mistake adding the objects to the NSMutableArray though. Should you just be able to do '[knobs addObject: knob0];' for each object and have that code when the view loads?

Comment: Solved - needed to add the line myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; Thanks for your help :)